# How to postwalk parsely result?

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, clojure

I am looking at a clojure refactoring lib which uses [parsley](https://github.com/cgrand/parsley) to parse its syntax.
I upgraded parsley to 0.9.1, then one function fails.

Here is what that function does:
Suppose we have `"(defn a [b] (:foo b))"`, the refactoring tool will parse argumets and map lookups:`[b]` and `(:foo b)`. then convert `(:foo b)` to a map: `{b (foo :foo)}` and replace the symbol `b` in `[b]` with the map's value `(foo :foo)`. I should finally get `{(foo :foo)}`.

Following code is for the last step:

```
clojure.walk/postwalk-replace {#net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content ["b"]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :map, :content ["{" #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content ["foo"]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :whitespace, :content [" "]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content [":foo"]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :whitespace, :content [" "]} "}"]}}
                           #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :vector, :content ["[" #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content ["b"]} "]"]}
```

It reports:`UnsupportedOperationException Can't create empty: net.cgrand.parsley.Node  net.cgrand.parsley.Node (parsley.clj:19)

However, when I pprint `{#net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content ["b"]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :map, :content ["{" #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content ["foo"]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :whitespace, :content [" "]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content [":foo"]} #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :whitespace, :content [" "]} "}"]}}`

and

```
#net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :vector, :content ["[" #net.cgrand.parsley.Node{:tag :atom, :content ["b"]} "]"]}
```

then pass them to postwalk:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk-replace {{:tag :atom, :content ["b"]}
                            {:tag :map,
                             :content
                             ["{"
                              {:tag :atom, :content ["foo"]}
                              {:tag :whitespace, :content [" "]}
                              {:tag :atom, :content [":foo"]}
                              {:tag :whitespace, :content [" "]}
                              "}"]}}
                           {:tag :vector, :content ["[" {:tag :atom, :content ["b"]} "]"]})
```

everythins is fine, i got what i want`{:content
 ["["
  {:content
   ["{"
    {:content ["foo"], :tag :atom}
    {:content [" "], :tag :whitespace}
    {:content [":foo"], :tag :atom}
    {:content [" "], :tag :whitespace}
    "}"],
   :tag :map}
  "]"],
 :tag :vector}`

My question is: what does `#net.cgrand.parsley.Node` means in parsley? Why after I remove these notations(using pprint) the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Parsley's nodes are records, rather than regular maps. `#net.cgrand.parsley.Node{...}` is literal notation for this record type. Records can't be emptied (as with `clojure.core/empty`), `clojure.walk` functions rely on emptying collections with `empty`, therefore `clojure.walk` functions cannot operate on records.

It so happens that `pprint` omits the tag when printing records -- it simply prints them as regular maps -- so if you read back the `pprint`ed representation, you'll get a map, which can then be emptied, so you can pass it to `postwalk`.

The correct course of action depends on what exactly it is that you wish to accomplish. If you want actual `Node` instances, you'll need to write your own tree walker (perhaps adapting `clojure.walk/walk`); if you'd be alright with regular maps, you could write a very simple tree walker to replace `Node`s with maps in Parsley's output and then use `clojure.walk` on the transformed tree.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems I have to write my own tree walker since the lib uses Node instances everywhere. Thanks.